# How can I get to the value of my WPF UserControl DependencyProperty from UI Automation Framework?

Tags: wpf, testing, user-controls, properties, ui-automation

I'm having trouble getting access to my WPF UserControl DependencyProperty values through the UI Automation Framework.

I've used James McCaffreys article in MSDN as a starting point (Automating IO Tests in WPF Applications, MSDN March 2009), but I can only see properties etc in standard controls such as buttons.

I'm assuming there's some Automation interface I have to implement on my UserControl, but what and how?

I can already see my control fine e.g. in UISpy, but I can't see the dependency properties within it. Here's what my usercontrol looks like currently in UISpy:

AutomationElement General Accessibility AccessKey: "" AcceleratorKey: "" IsKeyboardFocusable: "False" LabeledBy: "(null)" HelpText: "Switches 48v Phantom Power On/Off (for Mic inputs only)."

State IsEnabled: "True" HasKeyboardFocus: "False"

Identification ClassName: "" ControlType: "ControlType.Custom" Culture: "(null)" AutomationId: "V48SwL" LocalizedControlType: "custom" Name: "" ProcessId: "5684 (VirtualSix)" RuntimeId: "7 5684 40026340" IsPassword: "False" IsControlElement: "True" IsContentElement: "True"

Visibility BoundingRectangle: "(140, 457, 31, 20)" ClickablePoint: "155,467" IsOffscreen: "False"

ControlPatterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of getting arbitrary Dependency Property values from UI Automation: you can only get [AutomationProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationproperty.aspx) values.

This [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/129d2ea6-91ae-4f65-b07e-c36684ae742b) says that in the new version of the UIAutomation API there is a way of adding your own custom AutomationProperties, but that version of UIA isn't supported by WPF yet.

A suggested workaround is to bind the Dependency Property your are interested in to the AutomationProperties.ItemStatus attached property: this will then be available in AutomationElement.Current.ItemStatus.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, I was afraid of that. Your workaround sounds good though, I'll give it a try.